# Many-to-One PostgreSQL course name: Unesco Heritage Sites Many-to-One

Tags: postgresql

I got issues with an assignment. The assignment was:

Here is the structure of the tables you will need for this assignment:

```
DROP TABLE unesco_raw;
CREATE TABLE unesco_raw
 (name TEXT, description TEXT, justification TEXT, year INTEGER,
    longitude FLOAT, latitude FLOAT, area_hectares FLOAT,
    category TEXT, category_id INTEGER, state TEXT, state_id INTEGER,
    region TEXT, region_id INTEGER, iso TEXT, iso_id INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE category (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

... More tables needed

To load the CSV data for this assignment use the following copy command. Adding HEADER causes the CSV loader to skip the first line in the CSV file. The \copy command must be one long line.
\copy unesco_raw(name,description,justification,year,longitude,latitude,area_hectares,category,state,region,iso) FROM 'whc-sites-2018-small.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
Normalize the data in the unesco_raw table by adding the entries to each of the lookup tables (category, etc.) and then adding the foreign key columns to the unesco_raw table. Then make a new table called Unesco that removes all of the un-normalized redundant text columns like category.
If you run the program multiple times in testing or with different files, make sure to empty out the data before each run.

The autograder will look at the UNESCO table.

To grade this assignment, the program will run a query like this on your database and look for the data it expects to see:

```
SELECT unesco.name, year, category.name, state.name, region.name, iso.name
  FROM unesco
  JOIN category ON unesco.category_id = category.id
  JOIN iso ON unesco.iso_id = iso.id
  JOIN state ON unesco.state_id = state.id
  JOIN region ON unesco.region_id = region.id
  ORDER BY year, unesco.name
  LIMIT 3;
```

[image: my result was]

[image: the expectation was]

The error the autograder provided was: Row 1 column 1 expected Aachen Cathedral , got Aachen Cathedral

The code I did was the creation of the tables: unesco, iso, year, category, state, and region. Also, inserted the values at the end on the UNESCO table using the foreign keys from the other tables.

Example:

```
Insert into unesco (name,iso_id,region_id,state_id,category_id,year) values ('Aachen Cathedral',1,3,1,1,1978);

insert into unesco (name,iso_id,region_id,state_id,category_id,year) values ('City of Quito',2,1,2,1,1978);

insert into unesco (name,iso_id,region_id,state_id,category_id,year) values ('Gal pagos Islands',3,2,3,2,1978);
```

Tables are:
[image: region table]
[image: state table]
[image: year table]
[image: category table]
[image: iso table]

Can you please help?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: For problems with assignment, please show us the code you ran and provide a [mcve]. For problems with the autograder, ask your instructor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question where you can easily include code with formatting instead of putting it in hard-to-read comments

Comment: Are these insert statements meant to be sample data for us, or your attempt at a solution? Notice that the assignment says you should import a CSV file.

Comment: I used the CSV file but later on to create the Unesco table I have inserted it.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you're meant to use generic SQL queries for that, not inserts of hardcoded values.

Comment: For example? @bergi

Answer (score 3):

Do this step by step

```
DROP TABLE unesco_raw;
CREATE TABLE unesco_raw (
  name TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  justification TEXT,
  year INTEGER,
  longitude FLOAT,
  latitude FLOAT,
  area_hectares FLOAT,
  category TEXT,
  category_id INTEGER,
  state TEXT,
  state_id INTEGER,
  region TEXT,
  region_id INTEGER,
  iso TEXT,
  iso_id INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE category (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE state (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE region (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE iso (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
\ copy unesco_raw(
  name,
  description,
  justification,
  year,
  longitude,
  latitude,
  area_hectares,
  category,
  state,
  region,
  iso
)FROM'whc-sites-2018-small.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
   
INSERT INTO category(name) SELECT DISTINCT category FROM 
unesco_raw;
INSERT INTO state(name) SELECT DISTINCT state FROM unesco_raw;
INSERT INTO region(name) SELECT DISTINCT region FROM 
 unesco_raw;
INSERT INTO iso(name) SELECT DISTINCT iso FROM unesco_raw;

UPDATE unesco_raw SET category_id = (
  SELECT category.id FROM category WHERE category.name = unesco_raw.category);
UPDATE unesco_raw SET state_id = ( 
  SELECT state.id FROM state WHERE state.name = unesco_raw.state );
UPDATE unesco_raw SET region_id = (
    SELECT region.id FROM region WHERE region.name = unesco_raw.region);
UPDATE unesco_raw SET iso_id = (
    SELECT iso.id FROM iso WHERE iso.name = unesco_raw.iso);

CREATE TABLE unesco (
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    justification TEXT,
    year INTEGER,
    longitude FLOAT,
    latitude FLOAT,
    area_hectares FLOAT,
    category_id INTEGER,
    state_id INTEGER,
    region_id INTEGER,
    iso_id INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO
  unesco(
    name,
    description,
    justification,
    year,
    longitude,
    latitude,
    area_hectares,
    category_id,
    state_id,
    region_id,
    iso_id
  ) select
  name,
  description,
  justification,
  year,
  longitude,
  latitude,
  area_hectares,
  category_id,
  state_id,
  region_id,
  iso_id from unesco_raw;

SELECT unesco.name, year, category.name, state.name, region.name, iso.name
  FROM unesco
  JOIN category ON unesco.category_id = category.id
  JOIN iso ON unesco.iso_id = iso.id
  JOIN state ON unesco.state_id = state.id
  JOIN region ON unesco.region_id = region.id
  ORDER BY state.name, unesco.name
  LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.